# notify HTTP requests sent from Android app

Tags: android, http

I have the application. I know all urls, parameters, http-request types, etc (this is my application).

How can I intercept all requests from the application?

For example:
I pressed a button and can see the text of requests to the server.

Task:
to hide requests from potential hackers and prevent him to perform requests on behalf of the application.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: i think encryption will help you, See AES encryption

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can see your requests with a Packet Sniffer.  If you are developing and testing on an emulator something like Wireshark, Fiddler, etc would work.  If you are developing and testing on a specific Android device, then try using apps like Packet Sniffer which will capture the requests going through.

If you want to secure the requests from hackers then consider encrypting your requests.  To start with, use SSL (HTTPS) encryption on your server, to prevent people from eavesdropping on the same network.  To set this up, it will depend on what server technology you are using (e.g. Apache, Nginx, etc).  However, there are many solutions but a popular one is LetsEncrypt.

Next, if you don't want people to understand the requests your app is sending to / from their device, then consider adding another layer of encryption on the request payload itself.  Algorithms such as AES256 bit encryption will work and be secure enough, have a look here: [Android AES 256-bit Encrypt data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198462/android-aes-256-bit-encrypt-data)

Always hash any passwords you are sending / storing too, using algorithms like MD5, SHA256, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No one can see that http request without source code .

If you upload your app in play store they have just apk . From that they cant do anything.Now a days google provides more security for applications.Because you are already generated singed Apk.